# What are the (non-piecewise) linear manifolds?

Tags: manifolds

For all non-negative integers $n$, $B_n$ is defined to be $\: \big\{\mathbf{v} \in \mathbf{R}^n : ||\mathbf{v}||<1\big\} \:$.

> For what manifolds does there exist an atlas of charts $\: c : U\to B_n \:$ such that the transition
>   
>   maps are all locally affine and the union of the domains of the charts is the entire manifold?

(Replacing "locally affine" with "piecewise affine" would make the answer, by definition,

those manifolds for which there exists a [piecewise linear](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise_linear_manifold) structure.)

By the definition I'm using, all manifolds are Hausdorff and second countable.

Comment: I'm asking this here instead of on MathOverflow because I think this would have already $\hspace{1.4 in}$ been considered somewhere and published somewhere. $\:$

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_manifold